# Position SeekBar on vertical edge of another View

Tags: android, android-layout, android-design-library, android-seekbar, android-coordinatorlayout

I'm working with Android's SeekBar, desperately trying to achieve a layout where such a SeekBar sits right on the vertical edge of another view.

Given the fact that other apps follow this kind of pattern, I know that this would work, I simply don't know what attributes and values I'd need to make it happen.

As of now, things look like the following:

[image]

Though what I have in mind would look more like this:

[image]

The SeekBar's xml tag is as follows:

```
    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:maxHeight="2dp"
        android:padding="0dp"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/appbar" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Move the seekbar *outside* the AppBarLayout, and use these attributes:

```
<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/seekBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/appbar" />
```

Comment: Try assigning a higher android:elevation value.

Comment: Sure that works but i try supporting android api lvl >=16 :(

Comment: Which API are you testing on? I believe that on API<21 the seekbar will always appear on top.

Comment: i am testing on 22. when what you say is true, i will add that android:elevation in layout-v21 only Thanks!